# php check if url exists

Tags: php, url

Is there a php way on how to check if the url is use now?

for example I have

```
http://site.com/login.php?action=submit
```

using isset($_GET[action])

we can check that action exists in the url

but how can I check if

```
login.php
```

is the one that is active url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if ( '/login.php' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) {
    // This is login.php
} else {
    // This is not login.php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to see if it contains login.php.  It contains the current URI.  See the PHP manual for $_SERVER here:  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php